# How to use MonoTouch to use C# application for iPad?

Tags: c#, ipad, xamarin.ios

How to use MonoTouch  to use C# application for iPad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try reading the [Tutorials](http://monotouch.net/Tutorials) section of the MonoTouch page, and the [iPad](http://monotouch.net/IPad) section?

If those didn't help you, please ask more specific questions about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Is MonoTouch alternative to MonoDevelop for IPAD?

Comment: Can I port my old C# desktop application on IPad using MonoTouch?

Comment: @Noro: Not easily, no. It's not a port of Windows Forms, for example. It's provides a binding to the native iPhone widgets.

Answer (score -1):

xamarin provides support for developing iphone/ipad application but it is not up to mark, it is worth for beginners but not for professionals, the books available also have many errors  there examples does not works fine, and monotouch is also not fully develop, many features of ios development are still missing and lot of help is not on net so i suggest you to please take time and try to learn objective c it is not too hard and it will help you a lot

Comment: how you can say that suggesting objc over c# gets an automatic downvote